# In Skyrim, is it possible to upgrade a weapon/armor twice?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I upgraded my Krosis mask, and it became flawless. I believed it to be the best quality, as something flawless, of course, doesn't have flaws.

It would seem that Legendary is the best quality. I can't upgrade it again, and I was wondering if anyone knew a way to upgrade it twice?

Any information would be greatly appreciated. (Through a mod, a in-game command, or a glitch, it does not matter to me.)

Answer (score 15):

There are no requirements to further upgrading a piece of equipment, you just need to have enough skill in Smithing to do so.

For example, let's say you upgrade an Iron Dagger to Fine quality and use it for a while. You play for a while, improve your Smithing and find an Elven Dagger, so you want to upgrade that too, and it becomes Flawless. That's because your Smithing skill is high enough that the upgrade applied to the dagger turns into Flawless quality. Now if you were to go back to your Fine Iron Dagger, you could upgrade that to Flawless as well, barring any perks that improve your, er, improvements.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes you can.

[UESP.net](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing#Item_Quality) has more exact details, but the relevant information is once you have increased your skill, you will be able to upgrade the same piece of equipment again.

You can increase you skill using any combination of the following:

- Skill Increase
- Obtain the relevant perk (not available for all equipment)
- Using a Fortify Blacksmith potion
- Wearing Fortify Blacksmith enchanted equipment

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Smithing skill. The higher the skill, the more you'll be able to improve armor/weapons. Don't forget to wear any items that are enchanted with Smithing.